# How to initialize progressbar and update it on recursive call

Tags: python-2.7, progress-bar

I am trying to build a function that will discover similar text files in a folder and move the unique files to a separate directory. The function is running well. What I need is to monitor the whole comparing process due to the fact that it’s time consuming task. So, I tried to incorporate “python-progressbar” (https://code.google.com/p/python-progressbar/). Unfortunately it crashes and gives the following error:

```
  File "C:\Users\anarchos78\Desktop\CompareForSimilarities\helpers.py", line 202, in compare
    for i in pbar(range(0, len(list))):
  File "C:\Users\anarchos78\Desktop\CompareForSimilarities\scripts\progressbar\__init__.py", line 181, in __next__
    else: self.update(self.currval + 1)
  File "C:\Users\anarchos78\Desktop\CompareForSimilarities\scripts\progressbar\__init__.py", line 271, in update
    raise ValueError('Value out of range')
ValueError: Value out of range
```

I think that the problem arises when I call the function recursively (see the last line below) the progressbar cannot be updated. The comparing function:

```
import progressbar

# Set up the progressbar
widgets = [progressbar.Percentage(), ' ', progressbar.Bar(), ' ', progressbar.ETA(), ' ']
pbar = progressbar.ProgressBar(widgets=widgets)

# Compare function
def compare(fileToWrite, list, sourcePath, singlesPath, groupsPath):
    if len(list) > 1:
        file1 = list[0]
        file1Path = os.path.join(sourcePath, file1)
        txt1 = open(file1Path)

        # Remove file not to examine for similarities with itself
        list.remove(file1)

        sameItems = {}
        sameItems.update({file1: fileLength(file1Path)})

        for i in pbar(range(0, len(list))):
            file2Path = os.path.join(sourcePath, list[i])
            txt2 = open(file2Path)
            examine = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, txt1.read(), txt2.read())
            ratio = formatRatio(examine.ratio())
            if ratio > 80:
                sameItems.update({list[i]: fileLength(file2Path)})

            largestFile = keyWithMaxValue(sameItems)
            copyUnique(sourcePath, largestFile, singlesPath)

            fileToWrite.write(file1 + ' <=> ' + list[i] + ' ' + str(ratio) + ' ' +
                               '%' + '. The stuct: ' + str(sameItems) + '\n')
            txt2.close()
        txt1.close()

        # Renew the list by removing the duplicates to pass it to our recursive call
        # [the purpose for this is not to do unnecessary file comparisons]
        for key in sameItems.keys():
            if key in list:
                list.remove(key)

        fileToWrite.write('\n')

        # Pass the renewed list to our recursive call
        compare(fileToWrite, list, sourcePath, singlesPath, groupsPath)
```

Is there any way to incorporate progressbar in a recursive function?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The progressbar likes to know the maximum value it's going to get. The first time `pbar(range(0, len(list)))` is called, the maxval is set.  The *next* time it's called, `progressbar` will get confused and raise the `ValueError` exception.

It's okay to have the progressbar not know how many updates it'll get (ie: maxval.) But if it ever thinks it knows, then it'll get confused if it gets a different maxval.

Create a number, add one to it each time through the loop, and pass this number to each call. Use the number to tell `progressbar` to update itself:

```
for i in range(1000000):
  # do something
  pbar.update(10*i+1)   # progressbar doesn't know the max, but works with larger numbers
```

see also: http://code.google.com/p/python-progressbar/source/browse/examples.py

Comment: But what happens when i call recursively the function (see last line of compare function). I think progressbar tries to update. Am i correct?

Comment: Yes. Progressbar wants to know its size. The first time `pbar` is called, it's called with a fixed-size iterator, so `pbar` sets `pbar.maxval=len(list)`. The *next* time pbar is called, it's called with a *different* length, so the library gets confused and raises a `ValueError`

Comment: Yes i got it. But where should i initialize the progressbar with the value of the first itteration (max value) and then with the renewed max value after the recursive call. Here is something that i'm missing.

Comment: If you know the max len, put it into the `ProgressBar(maxlen=123)` init call. If you don't, create a global number, increment it, and sent it into the `pbar.update(num)` call.